# This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

Wrapping a functioning query suddenly stops working with error message: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

In the following scripts, myschema.TX_By_Subject is a view of a view.
I've tried running the script by extracting the views' code and replacing all reference to the views by that code.
The result is the same, the first query (1) runs fine if the views' underlying code is used in place of the references to the views, but after that part is wrapped in order to calculate the ntile then Redshift suddenly choke and finds some unsupported correlated subqueries.

The following query (1) runs just fine:

```sql
select
  v_m_name as name
  ,usr_id as user_id 
  ,V_m_id || usr_id AS user_id_per_merchant   
  ,SUM(v_amt) sales_amt
  ,count(*) txn_count
from
  myschema.TX_By_Subject
where
  v_tx_id is not null and v_tx_id <> ''
  and
  v_subject =
    'Example Comp'
  and
  DT >=
    to_date('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  AND
  DT <=
    to_date('2019-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

But after wrapping it for adding ntile analytical function it suddenly finds a correlated subquery:

```sql
select
  q.*, ntile(10) over(partition by q.name order by q.sales_amt desc)
from
(
  select
    v_m_name as name
    ,usr_id as user_id 
    ,V_m_id || usr_id AS user_id_per_merchant   
    ,SUM(v_amt) sales_amt
    ,count(*) txn_count
  from
    myschema.TX_By_Subject
  where
    v_tx_id is not null and v_tx_id <> ''
    and
    v_subject =
      'Example Comp'
    and
    DT >=
      to_date('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    AND
    DT <=
      to_date('2019-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
) q
```

I would expect that wrapping a functioning query would not introduce errors regarding what's inside.

Comment: have you checked against the unsupported types documented here ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html

Comment: yes, but I don't think any of those are in my query. Still, I think it would be odd if the inner part works and it stops working when you use ntile.

Comment: OK, I think if you are going to get help with this you need to simplify the issue and make it repeatable using data and queries that you have provided in your question . please see and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example